# Flutter - Firebase Firestore. What is the best approach for storing and retrieving images

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

What is the best approach to store images from a flutter app to Firebase Firestore.

Currently Im retrieving the downloadUrl immediately after storing an image and then Im saving that into the pertaining document with a field called something like profileImage. Therefore, Im saving the url of the image in each document. Each user has a field called profileImage with a url to the storage location.

Then when rendering the user in a ListView Im using CacheNetworkImage referencing the user.profileImage to render the image.

Is this the right approach ? if not, what should be correct approach?

one scenario could be scrolling through page with a lot of cards of users each with a profile image. This makes a call to firestore every time the card gets rendered in the UI plus when the user updates the image I also have to update a document.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Asking for "the best" is unlikely to give you (great) answers, as it's subjective. If your current approach works for you, then that's . If there's a problem with your current approach, then edit your question to show a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and tell us what isn't working about it.  Also see: https://overflow.tips/problematic-questions#what-is-the-besteasiestfastest-way-to-do-x